# Highlight selected tab in asp.net master page with page refresh

Tags: jquery, asp.net, navigation

Iam trying to achive a very simple thing but didn't succeed. I have an asp.net website and have one master page with two child pages. I have two tabs for these child pages on master page. and the one is selected by default which is working fine at this point. When i click on the second tab its selected successfully with the code which i have below, but immedialtely page refresh and its again select the first default tab (whenever page refresh). I also use event.preventDefault() but it does not work.

So my question is simple that how to highlight the selected tab when i click on it, even the page is refresh, thanks.

Please view the code following:-

```
<style type="text/css">
               #header #toplevel-bar li.current {
                padding: 8px 7px 8px 7px;
                background-image: url("/include/images/button_back.jpg");
                border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
                color: white;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
 </style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#header #toplevel-bar ul li").click(function (event) {
            //event.preventDefault();
            $("#header #toplevel-bar ul li").removeClass("current");
            $(this).addClass("current")
         })
  })

 </script>

<div id="toplevel-bar">

        <ul>
             <li class="current"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="products.aspx">Products</a></li>
             <li><a href="Default.aspx">Services</a></li>
        </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your page refreshes as you click a link,you cannot add a class to it.Try checking the url and match it against the set of menu available.Something like this might help u ..

```
      var href = window.location.href;
      var lastSegment = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);  
      $("ul > li a[href$='" + lastSegment + "']").addClass("current");
```

Comment: This code (var href = window.location.href) is giving the previous page not the current one where i clicked. So how can i get the current page on tab click, thanks.

Comment: I also used this  (var tab = $(this).attr("href") but it is giving undefined error. please help me to get the clicked tab or url.

Comment: when u click the click does the page refresh..??